# Changing Title field placeholder text - Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

On my content type form I am trying to change the placeholder text from "Title" to "Subject". My field setting is as below:

[image]

This change gets updated correctly but the form title still shows as "Title" :

[image]

Unsure why it's not reflecting. Cleared cache and tried on incognito windows. no luck. Any help on how this can be fixed pls?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting on the correct content type and don't forget to hit `Save` button at the bottom of the `Manage form display` page.

If you have done all the above and still not solved the problem then somewhere in your code has overwritten the placeholder configuration of that field. In that case you need to find and remove it.